# How do I get the price of a line item for the transactions which are already completed?

Tags: commerce

There are some transactions which are made using drupal commerce module along with commerce ccavenue module. I have the order ids, transaction ids and list of line items purchased in each of the orders. But the problem is I if a product price is updated in past then I am not able to find the cost of the product in the past order when the product was purchased.

Is there any place where drupal stores product price for a particular order anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Commerce Module does store product amount of past order... You can retrieve using below details...

To get full details of order

```
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$view_mode = "administrator";
print entity_view('commerce_order', array($order->order_id => $order), $view_mode, NULL, TRUE);
```

To be more specific

```
  $order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
  foreach ($order->commerce_line_items['und'] as $line) {
    $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($line['line_item_id']);
    drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($line_item,1) . "</pre>");
  }
```

There is no chance it gets new price instead of old price since it gets tracked in `field_data_commerce_unit_price` table in database ... All you need to do is divide by 100 if decimal places are 2 in order line item amount...

[image]

Comment: I used commerce_order_load and commerce_line_item_load but its giving current price of product.

Comment: Just to make sure.. Purchase products and record order number.. Go and change product price.. Then execute above code using commerce_order_load and commerce_line_item_load.. You should get previous product price..

Comment: Sure, I will follow the same

Comment: Hi, the above answer did not solve the problem. So waiting for more answers

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try and use :

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_line_item_revision

that could activate the line items you are seeking